# Exception on BitmapFrame.Create (bug in WPF framework?)

Tags: c#, .net, exception, try-catch

I implemented a C# application that recevies frame RGB at framerate of 30fps.

The event of frame arrive is managed with this code:

```
void client_ColorFrameReady(object sender, ColorFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
    mycounter++;
    Console.WriteLine("new frame received: " + mycounter);

    if (writer != null)
    {
        count++;
        if (count % 2== 0)
        {
            using (var frame = BitmapImage2Bitmap(e.ColorFrame.BitmapImage))
            using (var thumb = ResizeBitmap(frame, 320, 240))
            {
                writer.WriteVideoFrame(thumb);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        writer.Close();
    }
}
```

with the if condition I manage only one of two frames.

When my code call `BitmapImage2Bitmap` I obtain this exception:

[image]

The exception in english should be:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in `PresentationCore.dll`
Additional information: BitmapMetadata is not available on BitmapImage.
```

The strange thing is that my application works "well" because the frames are correctly inserted in the output file.

I've read [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/9f23dde5-f281-4175-a6a2-5f4ad14a4dfe), so the problem seems a bug in WPF framework.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is by design.  A first-chance exception notification doesn't mean that there's a problem.  The relevant code inside the Create() method looks like this:

```
try
{
    metadata = source.Metadata as BitmapMetadata;
}
catch (NotSupportedException)
{
}
```

In other words, the exception is expected and simply swallowed.  Which is certainly very annoying since these exceptions *do* make the debugger stop when you have the Thrown checkbox checked in the Debug + Exception dialog.  But it certainly is not a bug, this was intentionally written this way.  Sometimes it is a lot cheaper to just let an exception be thrown and swallowing it instead of writing the code that prevents the exception.  Especially when it gets unpractical to avoid the exception, the case with bitmaps since there are so many different kind of bitmap types.  Some of which don't support metadata.  Wherever this is done inside the framework code, it is almost always done to make the code *faster*.  Speed is also an important aspect of code.

Feature, not a bug.  Untick the Thrown checkbox to avoid seeing these exceptions.

Comment: Thank you @Hans. But I have a problem: my application runs only if compiled in debug mode, release mode causes crash, so the exception I suspected might be the cause of the problem

Answer (score 15):

I hope my answer help you,

I had using same code, but BitmapFrame.cs (at PresetationCore.dll) occur Exception when we are using BitmapFrame.Create(source).

So, I just Using other create function below one, which is Inner function of BitmpaFrame.Create,

```
BitmapFrame.cs
     public static BitmapFrame Create(
        BitmapSource source,
        BitmapSource thumbnail,
        BitmapMetadata metadata,
        ReadOnlyCollection<colorcontext> colorContexts
        )
```

we can get same result `BitmapFrame.Create(source, null, null, null).`

- in your case, 
  `enc.Frames.Add(BitmapImage.Create(bitmap, null, null, null));`

thanks.

Comment: Thank you, this works great in my case without throwing any error message.

Answer (score 0):

Running with .NET Framework 4.5, I had to change the similar line in the Microsoft SDK WPF Photo Viewer sample from

```
  _image = BitmapFrame.Create(_source);
```

to

```
  _image = BitmapFrame.Create(_source, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.None);
```

to avoid the ConfigurationErrorsException.  Things seem to be drifting under the hood...

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this issue lately when dealing with images included in projects as Resources (BuildType=Resource in file properties). It seems to be some build related issue which makes the resources corrupt and causes what seems like random issues as WPF are loading them. Simply performing a clean/rebuild makes the error(s) go away. They may reappear when adding new images though but the same fix obviously applies.